# How to create a table for LaTeX out of multiple regression outputs from R?

Tags: r, list, regression

I have a list including multiple data frames (called a, b, ..., z). All data frames are built the same and look like this (with different values of course):

```
column1 column2 column3
8       4       5
9       9       7
2       7       9
6       6       6
7       7       2
```

I now run a regression for each of these data frames by using the following code:

```r
    regression <- lapply(list, function (x) 
      lm(x$column1 ~ x$column2 + x$column3, data = list))
```

The resulting intercept should be called **Intercept**, the coefficient for x$column2 should be called **Beta** and the coefficient for x$column3 should be called **Gamma**.

Now I want to create a table including the regression output for all data frames. Since I am also working with LaTeX, I want to include the table in my LaTeX document in a nice, academic layout. The table should look similar to this http://repec.org/bocode/e/estout/esttab012c.png

The input for the table should be for each data frame the coefficients for all three inputs and underneath the t-statistic in parentheses with star-signs marking the p-value (just like in the example provided above):

```
    Intercept   Beta    Gamma
a   8.0667      0.2664  -0.5905
    (1.266)     (0.294) (-0.929) 
b   ...
.
.
.
z
```

How can this be easily accomplished? Grateful for any tips (not an R-expert by the way so please be gentle).

Comment: I found the package **stargazer** to create these nice regression outputs for LaTeX but how do I create one table including all regression outputs for all data frames in the list?

Comment: Maybe using [texreg](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/texreg/vignettes/texreg.pdf).